# Getting Data from a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

I'm populating a C# DataGrid with some values, and I'd like to retrieve a value from a cell when I click on that.  How do I go about doing that with the .NET 1.1 Framework?

datagridview1 is not available in .net1.1

only for windows applications

Comment: What are you clicking on in the cell...Is it a linkbutton, a text,a button?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a web/ASP.Net 1.1 DataGrid:

1. Use `myDataGrid.Items` to get a row
2. Use `row.Cells[x]` to get a column in that row
3. Use `(TextBox)cell.FindControl("TextBox1")` to get a control inside the cell

For more info, see [Accessing a Control’s Value from DataGrid in ASP.NET](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work:

```
string strCell = (string)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent4.aspx, also found as a link in Eric Lathrop's answer. This covers most of the common scenarios.

Bear in mind that in the following example, `dataGridItem` is an alias for `MyDataGrid.Items[x]`, where x is the (row) index. This is because the following example is using a foreach loop, so if skimming keep that in mind.

> **Iterating through Rows of a DataGrid**
>   We have to iterate through rows of our DataGrid to get values of controls within that row, so
>   let’s do that first. The DataGrid control has a property called Items,
>   which is a collection of object DataGridItem that represents the
>   individual item in a DataGrid control, and we can use this property to
>   iterate through DataGrid rows by following these six steps.
>
> ```
> foreach(DataGridItem dataGridItem in MyDataGrid.Items){ 
>
> }
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value from a Bound Column in DataGrid**
>
> Our first column is a bound column, and we need to get a value written
>   in that column. DataGridItem has a property named Cells of which is
>   the collection of the TableCell object that represents the cells of
>   the row. The Text property of TableCell gives us the value written in
>   that particular cell.
>
> ```
> //Get name from cell[0] 
> String Name = dataGridItem.Cells[0].Text;
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value of a TextBox Control in DataGrid** Now our second column contains a TextBox control, and we need to get a Text property
>   of that object. We use the FindControl method of the DataGridItem to
>   get a reference for the TextBox.
>
> ```
> //Get text from textbox in cell[1] 
> String Age = 
> ((TextBox)dataGridItem.FindControl("AgeField")).Text;
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value from CheckBox Control in DataGrid**
>
> Our third column
>   in DataGrid contains a CheckBox Web control that we need to check if
>   the Checked property of that control is true or false.
>
> ```
> //Get Checked property of Checkbox control 
> bool IsGraduate = 
> ((CheckBox)dataGridItem.FindControl
> ("IsGraduateField")).Checked;
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value from CheckBoxList Web Control in DataGrid**
>
> This case
>   differs from the previous one because the CheckBoxList may return more
>   then one value selected. We have to iterate through the CheckBoxList
>   items to check if the user has selected a particular item.
>
> ```
> // Get Values from CheckBoxList 
> String Skills = ""; 
> foreach(ListItem item in 
> ((CheckBoxList)dataGridItem.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")).Items) 
> { 
>   if (item.Selected){ 
>       Skills += item.Value + ","; 
>   } 
> } 
> Skills = Skills.TrimEnd(',');
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value from a RadioButtonList Web Control in a DataGrid**
>
> We use the FindControl method of the DataGridItem to get a reference for
>   RadioButtonList and then the SelectedItem property of the
>   RadioButtonList to get the selected item from RadioButtonList.
>
> ```
> //Get RadioButtonList Selected text 
> String Experience = 
> ((RadioButtonList)dataGridItem.FindControl("RadioButtonList1"))
>     .SelectedItem.Text;
> ```
>
> **Getting the Value from a DropDownList Web Control in a DataGrid**
>
> This is similar to a RadioButtonList. I have used this control just to show
>   that it works the same way as any other ListControls. Similarly, you
>   can work with a ListBox Web control as we did with the CheckBoxList
>   control.
>
> ```
> //Get DropDownList Selected text 
> String Degree = 
> ((DropDownList)dataGridItem.
> FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Text;
> ```